# Exporting table from Amazon RDS into a csv file using Golang API

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rds

I am looking for some way to directly export the SQL query results to a CSV file from AWS lambda. I have found this similar question - [Exporting table from Amazon RDS into a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536224/exporting-table-from-amazon-rds-into-a-csv-file). But it will not work with the AWS Golang API.

Actually, I want to schedule a lambda function which will daily query some of the views/tables from RDS(SQL Server) and put it to the S3 bucket in CSV format. So, I want to directly download the query results in the CSV form in the lambda and then upload it to S3.

I have also found [data pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) service of AWS to copy RDS data to S3 directly, but I am not sure if I can make use of it here.

It would be helpful if anyone can suggest me the right process to do it and references to implement it.

Comment: Are you lloking for this `query results to a CSV file in the local machine` or `I want to schedule a lambda function` (I assume you refer to AWS lambda). Running code in cloud and in local machine are two different things.

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski Sorry for the confusion. I want to schedule a lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

> You can transfer files between a DB instance running Amazon RDS for
>   SQL Server and an Amazon S3 bucket. By doing this, you can use Amazon
>   S3 with SQL Server features such as BULK INSERT. For example, you can
>   download .csv, .xml, .txt, and other files from Amazon S3 to the DB
>   instance host and import the data from D:\S3\into the database. All
>   files are stored in D:\S3\ on the DB instance

Reeference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/User.SQLServer.Options.S3-integration.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I want to query data from RDS(SQL Server) and not Aurora.

Comment: Following the documentation, I have created the IAM role and set up it into the RDS instance. But even after spending so much time, I couldn't create a stored procedure to export the result in CSV. I am getting this error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602890/unable-to-create-a-stored-procedure-on-ssms