# Unable to create a stored procedure in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in SSMS to export the query result to CSV. But I am getting below error while creating.

SQL statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectUsers
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM [IMBookingApp].[dbo].[usertest]
    INTO OUTFILE 'C:/S3/users.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
GO;
```

Error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SelectUsers, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079666/how-to-produce-an-csv-output-file-from-stored-procedure-in-sql-server. THere is no flagged answer there one with a vote that will solve it for you

Comment: That syntax doesn't exist in T-SQL at all; there is no `INTO OUTFILE` command. This seems like you would be better off with `bcp` in a CLI or `OPENROWSET`.

Comment: On using this command in SSMS - `BCP master..[IMBookingApp].[dbo].[userTEST] out c:\S3\users.csv -c -t, -T ` . I am getting error as `Incorrect syntax near '.'` and it also saying `Could not find stored procedure 'BCP'`

Comment: Please use single '.' (BCP master.[IMBookingApp].[dbo].[userTEST]).

Comment: It is giving the same error even with single '.'

Comment: *"On using this command in SSMS"* @RahulSatal ... I said *"with `bcp` in a **CLI**"*. SSMS isn't a CLI, it's an IDE. Powershell is a CLI.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "[IMBookingApp].[dbo].[userTEST]" out "c:\S3\users.csv" -c -t, -T'
```

or try

```
bcp "select * from [IMBookingApp].[dbo].[userTEST]" queryout "c:\S3\users.csv" -c -t, -T
```

from the command line

Comment: It is giving this error -`The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.`

Comment: Please follow the steps provided in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016669/getting-execute-permission-to-xp-cmdshell

Comment: I have looked into that it and it seems use of `xp_cmdshell` is not recommended. Also, I am working on production database, So I don't want to make any changes to it. Can you suggest any other way?

Comment: You would actually be making changes to the Server, not the database, if you *were* to enable `xp_cmdshell`, @RahulSatal .

Comment: Now getting the error - `You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement.` Upon some research, I found that for making that change I need to be either sysadmin or serveradmin and unfortunately which I am not.

Comment: try the following by going to Query-->SQLCMD Mode   :OUT c:\S3\users.csv
SELECT * FROM [IMBookingApp].[dbo].[userTEST]

Comment: did you try running the bcp utility from the command prompt? try bcp "select * from [IMBookingApp].[dbo].[userTEST]" queryout "c:\S3\users.csv" -c -t, -T from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE SelectUsers
AS

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/S3/users.csv'
FROM [IMBookingApp].[dbo].[usertest]
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';GO;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Sumit. But I am using SQL Server which doesn't support `OUTFILE`. It only works with MYSQL.

Comment: You can refer to this blog and this is going to resolve you issue for sure. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/export-a-ssms-query-result-set-to-csv

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this blog and this is going to resolve you issue for sure.
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/export-a-ssms-query-result-set-to-csv