# How to speed up to make save file from database

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have a mysql database. It's very huge database. When I select the data with 1M records, I should make the csv file on the disk. 
I make the PHP script. But It's killed by Linux. 
How can I make the PHP script with fast speed?

```
        $batches = $itemcount / 50000; 
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $batches; $i++) {

            $offset = $i * 50000;
            $sql = $sql_org . " LIMIT  $offset, 50000 ";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);


            if($stmt) {
                if($stmt->execute()) {
                     $stmt->bind_result($FIRSTNAME, $LASTNAME, $PHONE....
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: Yes. It's not execution time. I run the PHP script in terminal.

Comment: There are 1M records. So it's occured memory overflow.

Comment: Maybe do it in chunks of 10,000 or whatever works and append to the CSV each time.

Comment: Did you tried to fetch database data by small chunks, for example 1k records per query?

Comment: why do you nt make it directly out of mysql with oufile. In terminal it doesn't really matter how big it is and skip php

Comment: I already used the small chunks.  50000 lines. But Making the csv file in AWS server will take 2 hours.

Comment: Use something like `SELECT blah blah FROM foo WHERE what INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`  You don't need PHP.

Comment: Make it smaller. Are you using some ORM's or smth like that? Maybe there's some memory leak in your code, it would help if you provide the full snippet.

Comment: $batches = $itemcount / 50000; 
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $batches; $i++) {

                $offset = $i * 50000;
                $sql = $sql_org . " LIMIT  $offset, 50000 ";
                
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        
        
                if($stmt) {
                    if($stmt->execute()) {
                        $stmt->store_result();
                        if($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
                            fclose($output);
                            return 0;
                        }

Comment: @HeZhiYong you try use $stmt->free_result() to free already stored data.

Comment: Linux doesn't kill programs randomly, there's a reason. Is it the OOM killer? (out of memory killer) if it's the case you can see that in the last lines of `dmesg`. If you're not sure try to increase your memory (adding physical or increasing the swap) and see if the program stil lgets killed. Also try to figure what signal it got.

Answer (score 1):

Install mysql client and [piping out the output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9536680/3849743)

```php
shell_exec('mysql -u username -p "password" --database=dbname --host=AWShostname --port=AWSport --batch 
  -e "select * from `table`" 
  | sed #s/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g# > /path/to/yourlocalfilename.csv')
```

Note: exporting huge amount of data from AWS is to expensive.