# Exporting data from mysql RDS for import into questDb

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, questdb

I've got a big table (~500m rows) in mysql RDS and I need to export specific columns from it to csv, to enable import into questDb.

Normally I'd use `into outfile` but this isn't supported on RDS as there is no access to the file system.

I've tried using workbench to do the export but due to size of the table, I keep getting out-of-memory issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out with help from this: [Exporting a table from Amazon RDS into a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536224/exporting-a-table-from-amazon-rds-into-a-csv-file)

This solution works well as long as you have a sequential column of some kind, e.g. an auto incrementing integer PK or a date column. Make sure you have your date column indexed if you have a lot of data!

```
#!bin/bash

# Maximum number of rows to export/total rows in table, set a bit higher if live data being written
MAX=500000000
# Size of each export batch
STEP=1000000

mkdir -p parts

for (( c=0; c<= $MAX; c = c + $STEP ))
do
   mysql --port 3306 --protocol=TCP -h <rdshostname> -u <username> -p<password> --quick --database=<db> -e "select column1, column2, column3 <table> order by <timestamp> ASC limit $STEP offset $c" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > export$c.csv

   # split down in to chunks under questdbs 65k line limit
   split -d -l 64999 --additional-suffix=.csv $FILE_NAME.csv ./parts/$FILE_NAME

done

# print out import statements to a file
for i in $(ls -v ./parts); do echo "COPY reading from '$i';" >> import.sql; done;
```

A slightly different approach which may be faster depending on indexing you have in place is step through the data month by month:

```
#!bin/bash
START_YEAR=2020
END_YEAR=2022

mkdir -p parts

for (( YEAR=$START_YEAR; YEAR<=$END_YEAR; YEAR++ ))
do
   for (( MONTH=1; MONTH<=12; MONTH++ ))
   do

      NEXT_MONTH=1
      let NEXT_YEAR=$YEAR+1
      if [ $MONTH -lt 12 ]
      then
         let NEXT_MONTH=$MONTH+1
         NEXT_YEAR=$YEAR
      fi

      FILE_NAME="export-$YEAR-$MONTH-to-$NEXT_YEAR-$NEXT_MONTH"

      mysql --port 3306 --protocol=TCP -h <rdshost> -u app -p<password> --quick --database=<database> -e "select <column1>, <column2>, round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<dateColumn>)) * 1000000 as date from <table> where <table>.<dateColumn> >= '$YEAR-$MONTH-01 00:00:00' and table.<dateColumn> < '$NEXT_YEAR-$NEXT_MONTH-01 00:00:00' order by <table>.<dateColumn> ASC" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > $FILE_NAME.csv

      # split down in to chunks under questdbs 65k line limit
      split -d -l 64999 --additional-suffix=.csv $FILE_NAME.csv ./parts/$FILE_NAME
   done
done

# print out import statements to a file
for i in $(ls -v ./parts); do echo "COPY reading from '$i';" >> import.sql; done;
```

The above scripts will output a `import.sql` containing all the sql statements you need to import your data. See: https://questdb.io/docs/guides/importing-data/

Comment: Now updated the answer to include splitting the export into chunks smaller than 65k which is a limit imposed by questdb when importing in this manner.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `split` can process its standard input, so you can skip the temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: this solution would work only if exporting the whole table, not when exporting specific columns**

You could try using mysqldump with extra params for CSV conversion. AWS [documents how to use mysqldump with RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html) and you can see [at this stackoverflow question how to use extra params to convert into CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040816/dump-all-tables-in-csv-format-using-mysqldump).

I am quoting here the relevant part from that last link (since there are a lot of answers and comments)

```
mysqldump <DBNAME> <TABLENAME> --fields-terminated-by ',' \
--fields-enclosed-by '"' --fields-escaped-by '\' \
--no-create-info --tab /var/lib/mysql-files/
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't specify a subset of columns with mysqldump, given the size of this table, I want to be as frugal as possible in the data I export.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` syntax to export the data to a file on the server.
You can then use the `mysql` command line client to connect to the RDS instance and retrieve the file from the server.
The only slight snag is that `mysql` won't connect to the RDS instance unless the instance is in a VPC, so if it isn't you'll need to connect to a bastion host first, then connect to the RDS instance from there.
`SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mytable.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

You can then get the file from the server:
`mysql -uusername -p -hmyrds.rds.amazonaws.com -P3306`

When you have a prompt from the `mysql` command line client you can retrieve the file using the `SELECT` command:
`SELECT LOAD_FILE('/tmp/mytable.csv');`

You can then pipe the output to a file using:
`SELECT LOAD_FILE('/tmp/mytable.csv') INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mytable_out.csv';`

You can then use the `mysql` command line client to connect to your questDB instance and load the data.
If you want to retrieve a specific column then you can specify the column name in the `SELECT` command when creating the file on the RDS server:
`SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM mydb.mytable INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mytable.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

Comment: Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the FILE privilege(s) for this operation

Pretty sure this is well known limitation of RDS?