# Moving deleted records to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to move the records from table `studentrecords` to `passivestudents` but i am not being able to. so far i've tried.

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","learndb");
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed this is the error: " . $db->connect_error);
       }
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO passivestudents VALUES (DELETE FROM studentrecords WHERE id=$id)";
    $result=$db->query($sql);
    if(!$result)
    {
        echo"ERROR MOVING";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<center><p style=\"color:green\">Information Moved!</p></center>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This was answered in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821736/mysql-move-rows-from-one-table-to-another), moving from one table to another

Comment: @QuintonZinn tried that.

Comment: Reverse your queries sequence first insert in the second table and then delete from first one.

Comment: You can't use where clause inside INSERT query. Try update instead of it. Also you query is wrong. You have to get the results before inserting it into another table.

Answer (score 0):

your query was wrong . you want to remove student with some id ? true ?

so follow these step:

1-`INSERT INTO your_sec_table (select * from first_Table where id= $id;`

2-`DELETE FROM first_table WHERE id=$id`

Comment: i've tried this $sql=`"INSERT INTO passivestudents (select* FROM studentrecords WHERE id=$id);
 DELETE FROM studentrecords WHERE id=$id";

$result=$db->query($sql);`
but failed.

Comment: `$sql1="INSERT INTO passivestudents (select* FROM studentrecords WHERE id=$id)"; $sql2="DELETE FROM studentrecords WHERE id=$id"; $db->query($sql1); $db->query($sql2);`@micky

Comment: do you have teamviewer software?

Comment: You must debug your code , to see which part have error! , maybe field doesn't match , or other reasons.