# INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to insert all data from one table to another in postgreSQL but do not why I keep running into this error. Can someone please help out here.

[mysql - move rows from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821736/mysql-move-rows-from-one-table-to-another)

```
insert into rejected
select * from data 
where Actual_Sale_Date = '03/08/2015' 
and Last_Name_First_Name = 'Cindy'
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 3: select * from data
```

Comment: *Always* list the columns when you are doing an insert, both for the `insert` and the `select`.  The problem will then go away and your code will be safer and clearer.

Comment: Thanks, but the MySQL linked I have attached utilizes the * in the snippet. Is * possible in postgreSQL?

Comment: It's possible, as long as the two tables have the same data structure.  Having said that, why not simply add a new column to data called status, or something like that.

Comment: The rejected is exactly the same structure as the data table. That is the very reason for the asterisk.

Comment: If the two tables had the same data structure, you would not get that error message.

Comment: Thanks I got my mistake now, there is a serial primary key inserted.