# UNPIVOT mysql data to other table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have the following mysql data

```
INSERT INTO `monthly` (`id`, `year`, `stat_id`, `cat_id`, `January`, `February`, `March`, `April`, `May`, `June`, `July`, `August`, `September`, `October`, `November`, `December`) VALUES
(1, '2017', '12', '25', '1', '3', '1', '1', '3', '4', '4', '2', '4', '', '', ''),
```

and i would like it to be convert to be like this

```
INSERT INTO `monthlydata` (`id`, `year`, `monthName`, `stat_id`, `cat_id`, `data`) VALUES
(1, '2017', 'January', '12', '25', '1'),
(2, '2017', 'February', '12', '25', '3'),
(3, '2017', 'March', '12', '25', '1'),
(4, '2017', 'April', '12', '25', '1'),
(5, '2017', 'May', '12', '25', '3'),
(6, '2017', 'June', '12', '25', '4'),
(7, '2017', 'July', '12', '25', '4'),
(8, '2017', 'August', '12', '25', '2'),
(9, '2017', 'September', '12', '25', '4'),
(10, '2017', 'October', '12', '25', ''),
(11, '2017', 'November', '12', '25', ''),
(12, '2017', 'December', '12', '25', ''),
```

is there an easier way to do this using mysql/php

Comment: [INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: do you want to transform the `INSERT INTO` string using PHP or your existing MySQL data?

Comment: i want to use mysql through phpmyadmin

Comment: After looking at your table, I doubt it's possible with just Mysql not in one query at least.  Because you have to pivot the table.  Well you could do 12 Unions, but that's less then Ideal... lol

Comment: What is the field `data` in to TO table?

Comment: You can copy the table like this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343644/in-mysql-how-to-copy-the-content-of-one-table-to-another-table-within-the-same)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `UNPIVOT` your data. MySQL doesn't have a built in function to do that so you'll need to use multiple queries.

```
INSERT INTO `monthlydata` (`id`, `year`, `monthName`, `stat_id`, `cat_id`, `data`) VALUES
SELECT id, year, 'January', stat_id, cat_id, January
    FROM monthly WHERE monthName = 'January'
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, year, 'February', stat_id, cat_id, February
    FROM monthly WHERE monthName = 'February'
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, year, 'March', stat_id, cat_id, March
    FROM monthly WHERE monthName = 'March'
.....
```

`ID` column here might cause issues. Depending on how you have defined it. If it is auto generated then you can remove it from the INSERT and let it be auto generated. Since you'll have rows for all months with same `ID`, you need to handle that scenario.

Comment: Thank You Bro..this does it